# Error caught in java

Tags: java, exception

Throwable is at the top of exception hierarchy and its two immediate subclasses are :

1. `Exception`
2. `Error`

According to the most famous programming books (Herbert Schildt, The complete reference), Exception *can be* caught and processed but an `Exception of type ERROR cannot be caught and processed because they are due to some problems which we can't get rid of!

But this code worked like normal. Dont know how or why.

before commenting, please execute the code fragment, the strange thing is that it works and both println statements are executed

```
class ExceptionTest {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        try {
            throw new StackOverflowError();
        } catch(Error e) {
            System.out.println("caught and processed " + e);
        }
        System.out.println("finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code as code, not as a screenshot.

Comment: java the complete reference by herbert schildt, 7th edition, page 206

The other branch is topped byError, which defines exceptions that are not expected to
be caught under normal circumstances by your program. Exceptions of type Errorare used
by the Java run-time system to indicate errors having to do with the run-time environment,
itself. Stack overflow is an example of such an error. This chapter will not be dealing with
exceptions of type Error, because these are typically created in response to catastrophic failures
that cannot usually be handled by your program.

Comment: "not expected to be caught" is not the same as "cannot be caught".

Comment: read the last line : " that cannot usually be handled by your program "

Answer (score 6):

It's not *cannot*, it's *should not**. Checked exceptions are designed to be thrown when there's an expected error condition the program should recover from (think printer out of paper, network connection dropped, etc). Unchecked exceptions and errors are designed to be thrown when there's a bug, or some unrecoverable condition has occurred (out of memory, stack overflow, etc.) hence you don't want to swallow these conditions, you want to deal with the problem that caused them so they don't occur in the first place.

Occasionally there's times when catching an unchecked exception (something that subclasses `RuntimeException`) is necessary (catching a `NumberFormatException` when trying to parse a user entered integer for example) - but there's almost never a time when it's good to catch an error.

As you've found, there's nothing on the technical side that prevents you from catching an error the same way you would catch an exception - heck you can even catch stack overflow and out of memory errors if you want to. It's just that in pretty much all cases this is a bad idea!

*Quoting from the book:

> One branch is headed by Exception. This class
>   is used for exceptional conditions that user programs **should** catch. [...] The other branch is topped by Error, which defines exceptions that are **not expected** to
>   be caught under normal circumstances by your program. [...] This chapter will not be dealing with
>   exceptions of type Error, because these are typically created in response to catastrophic failures
>   that cannot usually be handled by your program.

(Bolding is mine.)

Note the last sentence is talking about the conditions that create the errors not being able to usually be handled by the program, not the error object that's created and thrown. Sure, I can catch a `StackOverflowError` or an `OutOfMemoryError`, but I can't do *anything* in code that really solves those problems once I've caught them - I need to solve some bug in the code to prevent the error from occurring in the first place.

Comment: hello brother, i am not too good at advanced concepts, so explain me in simpler words.

first of all, the above code fragment is working FINE .
and is printing both the println statements, but how a CATASTROPHIC ERROR like stack overflow is being handled using exception handling ?

Comment: Well first off, you haven't actually *caused* a stack overflow error, you've just created the error object that represents it - so there's no catastrophic error occurring in your code at all. If there was, then I you could still do this, but the VM would essentially throw away the stack information and carry on (not a situation you want to be in at all.) It doesn't just magically "recover" because you've caught the error.

Answer (score 1):

`Exception` and `Error` both can be caught.
But you can't recover after the `Error`,that is there is no use of catching it.So we should not catch the `Error`

> For example during OutOfMemoryError, if you catch it you will get it again because GC may not be able to free memory in first place.

but you can recover from the `Exception`.

> For example FileNotFoundException occurs if the specified file not available then you catch it and you can provide any other file and continue the programm.

Comment: just run the above code fragment, it executes, even being an ERROR type